# A read-only derived REST resource?

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I am creating a new service in which I need to support tagging on two entities.
Can I create `/tags` as a top level REST resource which supports only following calls:

```
GET    /tags

GET    /tags/{tagName}
```

To apply tags, we use following calls:

```
PATCH    /entity1/{entity_1_Name}

PATCH    /entity2/{entity_2_Name}
```

So whenever a tag is applied to an entity, subsequent calls to `GET /tags` will show that tag. I am planning to do this, as this does not require me to store the tags independently in my data-store.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create /tags as a top level REST resource

Yes, you can. That sounds meaningful if `tag` is an independent entity and api response will contain only `tag_name` and other tag-related information only. It doesn't matter if your api has a database or web.config under the covers or it deals with hardcoded list of values. Your API interface **hides** this fact anyway and user will never know the details of implementation. It is okay to have a readonly entity.

> whenever a tag is applied to an entity, subsequent calls to GET /tags will show that tag

I'd expect that your resource model for `GET /entity2/{entity_2_Name}` will have a `tags` field:

```
class Entity2
{
    string entity_name;
    ...
    string[] tags
}
```

As an **alternative** you can fetch all data via two calls:

`GET /entity2/{entity_2_Name}` //has no tags array in a response

`GET /entity2/{entity_2_Name}/tags`

The resource `/entity2/{entity_2_Name}/tags` should return tags which are assigned to this concrete `entity2` instance

Comment: Is it a good idea to have /tags at top level that returns all the tags created in the system. The response will be a list of Tag objects, that contain their names and all possible tag values used for that tag.

Comment: @aman yes, it suits rest. If the amount of tags will grow in future and plain list will become incovenient for usage, you may want to extend this call with search: GET /tags?query=sometag